# Where to find the current positions and velocities of the planets?

Tags: astronomy, specific-reference, planets, solar-system, speed

I've written a program which simulates the motions of planets and other bodies. I'd like to run it on our own solar system, but to do so I need to know the current positions (preferably in heliocentric coordinates) of the planets as well as their current velocities. Is there a website where I can find this?

I've found all the positions of the planets [here](http://www.planetary-aspects.com/curr_asp/curr_posns.php), and I can find their average orbital speed fairly easily, but for some planets (e.g. Mercury) the orbital speed varies a fair amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it this still works: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=114165.

Comment: The link to the blog post in your previous edit worked perfectly! (Shockingly!) If you revert I'll be happy to accept.